# IBM cloud private Metering

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-pak-for-data

I have a query regarding Metering capability of IBM cloud private 2.1.0.1.

We are planning to set up an ICP environment for  multiple customers. So what options are ICP providing to get the usage and bill accordingly.
I have checked the ICP metering options and the information that got from ICP console is bare minimum.
ie 1. Memory usage
  2. Processor utilization (always higher value so not giving the accurate output
  3. Number of containers used.

Is there any other method to get the accurate metering data such as command line or other option ?
What is the best option to bill the customers based on their usage?
Request you to give suggestion on the above  queries.

Answer (score 1):

The capped cores (Ccores) is the number of cores a workload is allowed to access on a worker node.  E.g. a worker node may have 4 cores, but the workload container is only allowed to use 2.  Acores=4, Ccores=2.
The best/only way to do that right now is to use a namespace per customer